# Displaying timestamps for boolean values in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I am writing a feature in my Rails app that tracks packages. The way I currently have it set up, each package has many locations (let's say: location 1, location 2, location 3...) which are all initially false. When a package has passed through a certain location, the managers are supposed to mark that as true until it reached the final location. But in the show page for a package I want to show not only these true/false values, but also the exact time when a package passed through each individual location (when it goes from false to true). Any ideas how I might implement/display that?

Comment: Show your `Location` model

Answer (score 1):

Create a `marked_at` accessor on your class (or create a migration to add the marked_at field to the database):

```
class Package
  attr_accessor :marked_at

  def marked?
    self.marked_at.present?
  end
end
```

When a package is marked you can just set `package.marked_at = Time.now` and use `package.marked?` to check if it has been marked.

You can also add

```
def mark!
  self.marked_at = Time.now
end
```

to your class to mark it with `package.mark!` from outside. You can also do some logic in the `mark!` method, like passing in a location and checking if the location is the one where you want to mark your package:

```
def mark!(location)
  # check if we're at the correct location
  self.marked_at = Time.now if location = self.correct_location
end
```

Comment: I would imagine his Package class is an Activerecord model, so the attr_accessor probably isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try associations instead of field.

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
end
```

Then, give your `Location` the boolean attribute `present` and the string attribute `name`. When a package arrives at location 1, create a new location and set that location to `name: "location", present: true`. Flip the value when the package arrives at location2. Use `location.created_at` as a time stamp, or do the following:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
  after_create :mark_time
  after_save :mark_other_location_false

  def mark_time
    self.time_stamp = Time.now
  end

  def mark_other_location_false
    locations_list = self.package.locations
    other_locations = locations_list - self
    other_locations.map{ |l| l.present = false }
  end
end
```

This will set your timestamp and mark other locations false.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem that he needs some kind of a Timestamp instead of just a boolean field.

Comment: location1.created_at is your timestamp. Or, you can add an explicit timestamp field.